# Code delimiter in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I've forgot the reserved word before the # (or is it after?) for delimiter code snippets as I'd like.
You know the ones with the + for expanding the code and - for closing the code snippet. The ones the comes automatically in a class a method etc'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the name comes after the #

```
 #region MyClass definition
 public class MyClass 
 {
 ....
 }
 #endregion
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `#region`

```
#region foo

public static foo()
{
}

#endregion foo
```

However, [using regions is frowned upon](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/).